# Iranian National with U.S. Green Card need a transit visa? U.S > Vienna > Iran

Tags: visas, transit

I am planning to travel to Iran (I am Iranian also) from the U.S. (and I have a permanent residency card i.e. Green card holder) ... do I need a transit visa at Vienna airport?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No, you don't need a transit visa for Austria.

Long Answer: If an airline passenger is refused entry at a transit point or destination, the airline is required to return the passenger to the point of departure *at the airline's expense* (although they may try to recover the cost from the passenger). Thus, airlines are very careful to determine what documents are required by a particular passenger's travel before allowing that passenger to board. Airlines use the IATA database [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) to reveal what documents are required.

Putting your information into Timatic through [this online portal](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b) (there other others), generates this:

> National Iran (IR)
>   /Residence USA (US)
>
> Transit Austria (AT)
>   /Destination Iran (IR)
>
> ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Austria (AT)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Nationals of Iran, arriving from a
>   non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a
>   flight to a third country which is not a Schengen Member
>   State. They must:
>
> - have a residence permit issued by USA, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.
>
> ...
>
> Passport required.
>   - Nationals of Iran are allowed to enter with an expired passport
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.
>
> ...

Thus, because you will arrive from a non-Schengen state with an onward ticket for a third country which is not a Schengen state, you can transit in Vienna without a transit visa provided you stay in the airport's international transit area.

Comment: Thank you David for the information ... I actually called the airline (Austrian airline) and the customer service refused to answer and told me to contact consulate of Austria! ... I am checking your link, why I do not get those information that you provided? it just gives me a general information

Comment: @baldeagle67 at the linked duplicate you will find links to the EU legislation that says that having a green card exempts you from a transit visa requirement if you would otherwise have one.  But do be aware that you will not be permitted to go through passport control without a regular Schengen (type C or D) visa.  In particular, if you have any checked luggage it must be checked through, because you will be unable to reach the baggage carousel.

Comment: @baldeagle67 I presume you've not entered all the relevant information in the correct fields. I just entered your information again, and was rewarded with the same data. You could also try this different Timatic portal, which contains fewer fields and may be easier to use: https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html